# JAVA ERRO CONEXÃO BANCO DE DADOS | ANDROID STUDIO IGUANA

Tags: java, android-studio

ola, boa noite!

Entao meu codigo esta dando um erro na conexao com o banco de dados MYSQL Localhost, uso o wamp, nao estou usando API para a conexao com o BD;

Segue abaixo o codigo JAVA da página Cadastrar.java:

package com.example.apptcclivraria;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Cadastrar extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editTextRM;
EditText editTextSenha;
EditText editTextCodigoEtec;
EditText editTextEmail;
Button buttonCadastrar;

private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Biblioetec";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "root";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar);

    editTextRM = findViewById(R.id.editTextRMCadastrar);
    editTextSenha = findViewById(R.id.editTextSenhaCadastrar);
    editTextCodigoEtec = findViewById(R.id.editTextCodigoDaEtecCadastrar);
    editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailCadastrar);
    buttonCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.cadastrarBtnCadastrar);

    buttonCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cadastrarCliente();
        }
    });
}

private void cadastrarCliente() {
    String rm = editTextRM.getText().toString();
    String senha = editTextSenha.getText().toString();
    String codigoEtec = editTextCodigoEtec.getText().toString();
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

    if (rm.isEmpty() || senha.isEmpty() || codigoEtec.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        String query = "INSERT INTO usuario (rm, senha, CodigoEtec, Email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, rm);
        stmt.setString(2, senha);
        stmt.setString(3, codigoEtec);
        stmt.setString(4, email);

        int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rowsAffected > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cadastro realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Redirecionar para HomePage após o cadastro
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao cadastrar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Queria saber onde esta o erro, se é na Conexao, ou se é no Banco, ou se é o codigo inteiro. E se poderem me dar um exemplo/codigo, agradeço desde já!

Me ajudem ai Por Favor, vlwww!

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.